# flutter - google signin always the same error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-signin

I'm discovering flutter and I'm trying to create a simplistic google auth with firebase. I've seen a lot of tutorials and I arrived at this main.dart file

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  GoogleSignInAccount? _userObj;

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);

  void _login() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      setState(() {
        _isLoggedIn = true;
        _userObj = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  void _logout() {
    _googleSignIn.signOut().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoggedIn = false;
        _userObj = null;
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: _isLoggedIn
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_userObj!.photoUrl!),
                      radius: 50,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Welcome ${_userObj!.displayName}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _logout();
                      },
                      child: Text('Logout'),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _login();
                    },
                    child: Text('Login with Google'),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the page opens well in my emulator, when I click I can choose my google user.
Once selected, I always get this "error" :

[image]

it's quite frustrating because I don't know how to debug like a pro yet and it's blocking me for the comprehension of the classic auth flow.
Could you give me some hints knowing that I have the packages updated etc.

Comment: It seems like you're right in the debugger there, so did you already hover over `message` to see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the official [Firebase SDK for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start) and doing something like [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/#google). Hope I helped.